# Do I need to have played Breath of the Wild to understand the Tears of the Kingdoms storyline?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Do you need to have played Breath of the Wild to understand the story in Tears of the Kingdom?

Comment: Zelda botw is a masterpiece, one should play it regardless

Comment: @pinckerman definitely agree, but I’ve been asked the question twice now in person so I figured putting a question up here made sense.

Comment: It does, indeed. What I'm saying is that both are great games and I don't see the reason to "rush" and begin with the latest one. You can surely enjoy it, but you'll miss something special.

Comment: While the story elements are linear and follow somewhat directly from BotW, if you were going to ultimately play each one, I would recommend playing BotW first.  There are some gameplay elements/annoyances in BotW that were either smoothed out or fixed altogether in TotK.  The gameplay got a nice overhaul in TotK, enough that I would imagine playing BotW for the first time after it would not be quite as enjoyable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry, you don't have to be familiar with Breath of the Wild to enjoy Tears of the Kingdom. Of course, you might not catch all the references or the intricacies of the world, but the game has its own story that you can dive into without any prior knowledge.